# Selenium RC how make screenshot of html code while tests execution?

Tags: html, selenium-rc

I use selenium RC. My tests are failed after `waiForPageToLoad()` method. It doesn't find element on the page. I see on my browser what page is still loading while `waiForPageToLoad()` "said" that page is already loaded. How can I check how looks my HTML code just after `waiForPageToLoad()` method finished its execution?

One more thing. In one of occasions Element which sould be finded after `waiForPageToLoad()` is between the

```
<h1><script language="Javascript" </script>
<a id="some" class="some" onclick="">Text</a>
Text
</h1>
```

So could be that page is loaded but javascript is not yet executed. How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout specified in `waitForPagetoload()` method ? Also use `isElementPresent()` and `isVisible()` methods present in selneium RC.

Comment: I tried to increase timeout, but it doesn't help. Beside as I understand if the problem was in timeout I will get Timeout exception. It looks like methos said them page is loaded, but it is not true.

Comment: What are `isElementPresent()` and `isVisible()` methods  returning? true or false ?

Comment: those methods return false

Answer (score 0):

1) waiForPageToLoad() does not prove that you have all elements on the page. It is better to use waitForElementPresent, or check isElementPresent to find out if the element is on the page.

2) you did not mention what language you use in RC.

if java - you may use

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
...
public void captureScreen(String fileName) throws Exception {
   Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
   ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(fileName));
}
```

if C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
namespace SeleniumTests
{
[TestFixture]
public class ImageCapture
{
private ISelenium selenium;
private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
public static string CaptureScreenshot()
{
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(1024, 768, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics Screenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
Screenshot.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(1024, 768));
string name = (System.Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now).Replace("/", "_")).Replace(":", "_") + ".jpg";
bmpScreenshot.Save(name, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
return name;
}
```

3) if you develop in java - consider using Sikuli. It is a tool that works with images on the screen (you may use as java library). You may combine Selenium and Sikuli to get fantastic flexibility and functionality.